# Reading the 2nd entry of a .json

Tags: python

I am trying to read the density entry of a list of arrays within a .json file. He's a small portion of the file from the beginning:

```
["time_tag","density","speed","temperature"],["2019-04-14 18:20:00.000","4.88","317.9","11495"],["2019-04-14 18:21:00.000","4.89","318.4","11111"]
```

This is the code I have thus far:

```
with open('plasma.json', 'r') as myfile:
  data = myfile.read()

obj = json.loads(data)

print(str(obj['density']))
```

It should print everything under the density column but I'm getting an error saying that the file can't be opened

Comment: What's the error message, exactly?

Comment: Always post the full error message and stack trace (if any) when you're asking a "why am I getting this error" question. Without that we're as helpless as you at figuring out the issue.

Comment: The top answer fixed my problem perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you json file is not correct. If you want to read it with a single call `obj = json.load(data)`, the json file should be:

```
[["time_tag","density","speed","temperature"],["2019-04-14 18:20:00.000","4.88","317.9","11495"],["2019-04-14 18:21:00.000","4.89","318.4","11111"]]
```

Notice the extra square bracket, making it a single list of sublists.

This said, being `obj` a list of lists, there is no way `print(str(obj['density']))` will work. You need to loop on the list to print what you want, or convert this to a dataframe before.

#### Looping directly

```
idx = obj[0].index('density') #get the index of the density entry
                              #from the first list in obj, the header
for row in obj[1:]: #looping on all sublists except the first one
    print(row[idx]) #printing
```

#### Using a dataframe (pandas)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(obj[1:], columns=obj[0]) #converting to a dataframe, using
                                           #first row as column header
print(df['density'])
```

Comment: You're welcome. If you find the answer useful, please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I don't have high enough of a reputation to upvoted but I did accept it as the best answer. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

**Are you sure your data is a valid json and not a csv?**
As the snippet of data provided above matches that of a csv file and not a json.

You will be able to read the `density` key of the csv with:

```
import csv

input_file = csv.DictReader(open("plasma.csv"))
for row in input_file:
    print(row['density'])
```

*Data formatted as csv*

```
["time_tag","density","speed","temperature"]
["2019-04-14 18:20:00.000","4.88","317.9","11495"]
["2019-04-14 18:21:00.000","4.89","318.4","11111"]
```

*Result*

```
4.88
4.89
```

Comment: the file that I had downloaded was listed as a .json so I just assumed that is what it was

Comment: Fair Enough Zac, thats what I would have done too. But looks like you've got a CSV there, for which `csv.DictReader` will allow you to look up the data via a key.